# SAP B1 Service Layer slow performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wc, sap-business-one-di-api

I have been developing an application in MVC for SAP with DI API for a month, but due to administrative decisions the client will hire a cloud service, which only allows me to use "Service Layer". The last two weeks I have been transferring everything I had to this logic but it turns out that when I try to perform tests it takes a long time to load and display the data and the results.

Checking the internet I have found people who describe the same problems as me, but there are others who say that it works even faster than DI API.

Does anyone know if this is normal for Service Layer or has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference table for Service Layer response time. Can you relate to this?
[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28283049)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: It’s not exactly a link, but an image. They just didn’t have the reputation to embed it directly. It does seem to offer a valuable reference for the question, since the average response times are really slow.